# Set long version number in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Is it possible to set a long version number more for an flutter app? Note that may app is already launched in google play.

I want a version number be like this `3.0.25.1` in Google play ( .1 in the end).
The problem in Android studion -> pubspec.yaml when I set `3.0.25.1+133`

I got the following error

```
Error on line 14, column 10 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version number: Could not parse "3.0.25.1+133".
   ╷
14 │ version: 3.0.25.1+133 
   │          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
pub get failed
command: "C:\FlutterSDK\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\FlutterSDK\flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}
exit code: 65
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Step 1: Select Project and open in any IDE

Step 2: Select this open on right side after select you will see whole files in your project.

[image: Image description]

Step 3: Open App Level build.gradle file.

[image: Image description]

Step 4:- Search versionCode or versionName in this file you will find in defaultConfig map.

Step 5:- Add your version code and version name. keep in mind version code is build number. so in your case your versionName "3.0.25.1" .

[image: Image description].

Comment: Your solution worked, but is there any other file to set versionName? because it risky to open build.gradle and change the versionName on it. Thanks

Comment: I think no other way.

Comment: @blue492 if it was worked give up a vote to help other devs.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It mean

> The string that's being validated should match this pattern to pass the schema validation. For example, a valid string could be "1.2.3" or "1.2.3-alpha"or "1.2.3+12", while a string like "invalid-string" would not match this pattern.

Comment: I saw the message you mentioned, is it possible to solve my problem or not?

Comment: May be impossible.

Comment: Do you know the solution? thanks

Comment: Yes, he just told you... you can't have "1.x.x.x+x" as you can only have "1.x.x+x". The answer explains it why.